# For $m = m(n) \to \infty, {n \choose 2} - m \to \infty, N = {n \choose 2}$, we have $(1 + o(1))\sqrt{\frac{N}{2\pi m(N-m)}} \geq \frac{1}{10\sqrt{m}}$

Tags: proof-explanation, asymptotics, approximation

This is a step in a proof that I’m reading. How do we get this bound?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We divide both sides by $\sqrt{\frac{N}{2\pi m (N-m)}}$ and simplify to see that it suffices to show

$$\sqrt{\frac{2 \pi}{100}} \cdot \sqrt{1 - \frac{m}{N}} \leq 1 + o(1).$$

Now as long as $m = o(N)$, we know that

$$\sqrt{1 - \frac{m}{N}} \leq 1 + \frac{m}{2N} = 1 + o(1).$$

But $\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{50}} \approx 0.25 < 1$. In particular, this gives us

$$
\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{50}} \cdot \sqrt{1-\frac{m}{N}} \leq 0.251(1 + o(1)) \leq 1 + o(1)
$$

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Thanks. Do we get $m = o(N)$ by simply observing that $m \to \infty$ and $(N - m) \to \infty$ (hence $N$ tends to infinity faster than $m$), then putting it in the limit $\underset{n \to \infty}{\text{lim}}\frac{m}{N}$?

Comment: Good question! You have to be a bit careful, since, for instance, $2n - n \to \infty$ but $n \neq o(2n)$. That's why I stated the assumption on $m$ explicitly instead of driving it from yours. In fact, if $m = (n^2-n)/4$ you can see that the desired bound is NOT true. However, in many contexts (like Ramsey theory, etc) we have $m = O(n)$, which is good enough since $n = o(N)$.